# unicolumn gtktreeview behaves correctly, but multicolumn gives segmentation fault

Tags: c, gtk, segmentation-fault

I have a following issue with `GtkTreeView`.

The problem occurs when I'm trying to append the list. Here is my function which creates is:

```
  static GtkWidget *setup_list_archive(GtkWidget **widget)
  {
    GtkWidget *sc_win;
    GtkListStore *store;
    GtkCellRenderer *cell;
    GtkTreeViewColumn *column;

    sc_win = gtk_scrolled_window_new(NULL, NULL);
    gtk_widget_set_usize(sc_win, 250, 150);
    store = gtk_list_store_new(COL, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
    *widget = gtk_tree_view_new_with_model(GTK_TREE_MODEL(store));

    cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Klucz", cell, "text", ID, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(*widget), column);

    cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Data", cell, "text", DATA, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(*widget), column);

    cell = gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();
    column = gtk_tree_view_column_new_with_attributes("Godzina", cell, "text", CZAS, NULL);
    gtk_tree_view_append_column(GTK_TREE_VIEW(*widget), column);

    // scrolls behavior
    gtk_scrolled_window_set_policy(GTK_SCROLLED_WINDOW(sc_win), GTK_POLICY_NEVER, GTK_POLICY_AUTOMATIC);
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(sc_win), *widget);

    // free the objects
    g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(store));
    return sc_win;
  }
```

And here is my function which appends the list.

```
  static void list_add_archive(GtkWidget* widget, gpointer data)
  {
    arch *rekord = (arch*) data;
    printf("key: %s; pas: %s; dat: %s;\n", rekord->id, rekord->czas, rekord->data);
    GtkListStore *store;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    store = GTK_LIST_STORE(gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(widget)));

    gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
    gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, ID, rekord->id, DATA, rekord->czas, CZAS, rekord->data, -1);
  }
```

The problem occurs `only` with multicolumn kind of list. If I create list with one single collumn it works fine.

Here is my backtrace.

```
  key: 1; pas: 14; dat: 2013-06-22 12:24:58;

  Breakpoint 1, list_add_archive (widget=0x80e0c40, data=0xbfffe704)
at admin.c:512
  512       gtk_list_store_append(store, &iter);
  (gdb) step
  513       gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, ID, "a", DATA, "b", CZAS, "c", -1);
  (gdb) step

  Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  0xb76b8ff5 in g_type_value_table_peek ()
     from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgobject-2.0.so.0
  (gdb) step
  Single stepping until exit from function g_type_value_table_peek,
  which has no line number information.

  Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
  The program no longer exists.
  (gdb) step
  The program is not being run.
```

The line `g_type_value_table_peek, which has no line number information` made me think that maybe the enum which defines column numbers isn't correct, I've tryed to write just the integers instead of enum values. It didn't helped.

As you can see on the begging of my debbuger result, there's what printf prints on the screen and so the values in datastructure `record` exist and are correct. Anyway I tryed to put const chars in parameters and it changed nothing.

If I pass `null` as the parameter of the list it shows only a warning, like `invalid cast` et cetera, of course it doesn't work neither :) it's just strange there are no critical errors like segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, because you don't show the values of your constants, but you create a store with 2 columns, assuming `COL` equals 2:

```
gtk_list_store_new(COL, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
```

But then you store 3 values, which is not possible because the latter column does not exist:

```
gtk_list_store_set(store, &iter, ID, rekord->id, DATA, rekord->czas, CZAS, rekord->data, -1);
```

My guess is that you have an enumeration similar to:

```
enum { ID, DATA, CZAS, COL };
```

If that's the case, `COL` equals 3, not 2, and so the last column of the store is getting an undefined type. A very bad situation. To solve it, simply add the missing field in store creation:

```
gtk_list_store_new(COL, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING, G_TYPE_STRING);
```

If `COL` does equal 2, then you should change it to 3, and add the 3 types anyway.